# Can one use Map during Expand?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, memory, map

Can one `Map` a simplifying function to the summands of an `Expand` before fully expanding the expression in question first? Consider the following example:

I want to integrate the following product over `[0,1]` in the variable `t`.

```
imax = 30;
p1 = Product[a t^i + b t^(imax - i) , {i, imax}];
```

For that I define a custom integration (much faster than the general Integrate)

```
CustomIntegration[exp_] := exp /. t^k_. -> 1/(k + 1)
```

for which I have to use `Expand` first. The problem is that the expansion really eats a ton of memory, even though the final result is actually much smaller.

```
ByteCount@p1
ByteCount[p2 = Expand@p1]
ByteCount[CustomIntegration /@ p2]
```

gives

```
9376
1404216
13696
```

So, the expansion requires around 100-times as much memory as needed. My actual script currently needs around 70 GB of memory. So, how could I reduce that?

Answer (score 1):

In this specific case I believe that this will do the same operation in one command:

```
Collect[p1, a, CustomIntegration] // ByteCount
```

> ```
> 12728
> ```

```
Collect[p1, a, CustomIntegration] === (CustomIntegration /@ Expand[p1])
```

> ```
> True
> ```

However, this apparent success is false, as one can see using [`MaxMemoryUsed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MaxMemoryUsed.html) that much more memory is allocated:

```
(* in a fresh kernel *)

CustomIntegration[exp_] := exp /. t^k_. -> 1/(k + 1)
imax = 50;
p1 = Product[a t^i + b t^(imax - i), {i, imax}];

Collect[p1, a, CustomIntegration] // ByteCount
MaxMemoryUsed[]
```

> ```
> 29888
>
> 28313200
> ```

(Session baseline in v7 is 15MB.)

Answer (score 1):

I can't find a way to do it with both low memory and reasonable time consumption, but here is what I did when I encountered a similar problem. Basically you need to do some math for MMA.

### The math part

Your `p1` can be expanded by the so called [multi-binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#The_multi-binomial_theorem):

$$\begin{split}
p_1=&\prod_{k=1}^m (a\,t^k + b\,t^{m-k} )\\
=&\sum_{j_1=0}^1 \sum_{j_2=0}^1 \cdots \sum_{j_m=0}^1 \left(\prod_{k=1}^m \binom{1}{j_k}a^{j_k} b^{1-j_k}\right)\left(\prod_{k=1}^m t^{j_k k + (m-k)(1-j_k)} \right)
\end{split}$$

So we can see that there is an one-to-one map between $\{0,1,\dots,2^m\}$ and the set of all possible $\boldsymbol{j}:=(j_1,j_2,\dots,j_m)$, and we can program a loop on it. But let's go on for the moment.

Let $\nu_{\boldsymbol{j}}:=\sum_{k=1}^m j_k$, $\mu_{\boldsymbol{j}}:=\sum_{k=1}^m j_k k$,

$$
p_1=\sum_{\forall \boldsymbol{j}} a^{\nu_{\boldsymbol{j}}}b^{m-\nu_{\boldsymbol{j}}}\,t^{2\mu_{\boldsymbol{j}}-m\nu_{\boldsymbol{j}}+(m-1)m/2}
$$

Now we can substitute your integration rule into $p_1$, so `CustomIntegration /@ p2` should be

$$\begin{split}
I=&\sum_{\forall \boldsymbol{j}}\frac{a^{\nu_{\boldsymbol{j}}}b^{m-\nu_{\boldsymbol{j}}}}{2\mu_{\boldsymbol{j}}-m\nu_{\boldsymbol{j}}+(m-1)m/2+1}\\
=&\sum_{\nu=0}^m a^\nu b^{m-\nu}
\sum_{\forall \boldsymbol{j}(\nu)}\frac{1}{2\mu_{\boldsymbol{j}(\nu)}-m\nu+(m-1)m/2+1}
\end{split}$$

where $\mu_{\boldsymbol{j}(\nu)}$ is the $\mu_{\boldsymbol{j}}$ given $\nu$ out of $m$    elements of $\boldsymbol{j}$ equal to $1$ while others equal to $0$.

So what we need to do is to compute the coefficients of $a^\nu b^{m-\nu}$. And that is the place I failed.

---

### The program part

Here is what I tried.

First we setup some monitors:

```
miu = {MemoryInUse[]};
Dynamic[Refresh[
          AppendTo[miu, MemoryInUse[]];
          If[Length[miu] > 3000, miu = miu[[-3000 ;; -1]]];
          ListLinePlot[miu, PlotRange -> All],
        UpdateInterval -> 0]]

Dynamic[ListLinePlot[{target, sum}, PlotRange -> All]]
```

Then the result by your original method:

```
imax = 20; 
p1 = Product[a*t^i + b*t^(imax - i),  {i, imax}]; 
target = p1 // ExpandAll // CustomIntegration //
                  CoefficientList[#, {a}] & // # /. b -> 1 &;
```

Now my VERY slow (but memory-economical) way:

```
sum = ConstantArray[0, imax + 1];
Module[{m = imax, temp, base, μ},
       base = Range[m];
       Do[
          temp = 1 + (m (m - 1))/2 - m ν;
          Do[
             μ = Total[Subsets[base, {ν}, {c}][[1]]];
             sum[[ν + 1]] += 1/(temp + 2 μ),
           {c, Binomial[m, ν]}],
        {ν, 0, m}]
      ];

sum == target
```

> ```
> True
> ```

For `imax`$>20$ the time consumption will be unbearable. I believe a proper parallelization and compilation will make it a bit faster, but the gain might still be limited. Also, with a naive compilation, you loose the infinite precision.